# Wordpress Issues with showing changes on GoDaddy hosted Site

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I am currently working on a site that is hosted on GoDaddy's Wordpress-Managed hosting. I have had issues come up that I've never seen before. For example, I was working right on the FTP, saving my changes and uploading immediately, but none of the changes I made would show up on the server. I read about GoDaddy's restrictive cache so I worked locally until the theme was done. Even then, after I uploaded, the changes wouldn't show. I double-checked the style file on the server, it was updated, but I could not physically see my changes.

After a few hours, the changes showed. Now, however, I'm still struggling. The styles and JS updates will not show in Incognito or on certain computers. I'm at the end of my rope here on where to go and what to do. Is it something to do w/ my Wordpress functions file and the versioning of my CSS and JS? Does it have to do w/ GoDaddy's server? Would switching from GoDaddy's Managed Wordpress to a basic hosting and installing Wordpress myself be more efficient?

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: Are you calling the custom styles in the header or through the `functions.php` file? There is always a caching issue when calling them through the header file.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I'm calling them through the functions.php file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me out! It actually all had to do with GoDaddy and their server side caching. For some reason, the files were taking roughly twenty minutes to show changes. I just started working locally and uploading only when I needed to. Don't know if that's the best solution, but it's working for this simple site.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is caching server side (for example some caching modules will cache all PHP files for a given period of time).

The quick and dirty solution is to add a query string to the file(s) you are trying to view to see changes immediately.

Example:
http://mywebsite.com/somefile.php**?hucd8239812**

You will need to change the query string every time you change the file, but it's a quick and dirty way to break cache.